# Apparent method call after destruction in olcSoundMaker.h

Tags: c++, access-violation

*I couldn't come up with a better title, so feel free to give suggestions.*

I tried to follow OneLoneCoder's [tutorial on sound synthesizing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgamhuQnOkM), I'm only halfway through the first video and my code already throws an exception.
All I did was downloading his `olcSoundMaker.h` from [his github](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/synth), and copying the entry point:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "olcNoiseMaker.h"

double make_noise(double time)
{
    return 0.5 * sin(440.0 * 2 * PI * time);
}

int main()
{
    std::wcout << "Synthesizer, part 1" << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::wstring> devices = olcNoiseMaker<short>::Enumerate();

    for (auto d : devices)
    {
        std::wcout << "Found output device: " << d << std::endl;
    }

    olcNoiseMaker<short> sound(devices[0], 44100, 1, 8, 512);
    sound.SetUserFunction(make_noise);

    while (1) { ; }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the video he runs this just fine; for me, it starts producing a sound, then after 60-80 iterations of the `while (1)` loop, it stops and raises this:

```cpp
Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
std::_Atomic_address_as<long,std::_Atomic_padded<unsigned int> >(...) was 0xB314F7CC.
```

(*from the `<atomic>` header file, line 1474.*)

By stepping through the code with VS I didn't find out much, except that it happens at different times during every run, which may mean it has something to do with multithreading, but I'm not sure since I'm not very familiar with the topic.

I found [this question](https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-unhandled-exception-thrown-write-access-violation-error.29892/#login) which is similar, but even though it says [SOLVED] it doesn't show me the answers.

Anyone that can help to get rid of that exception?

Comment: Given the output, there are no found output devices, and then the code accesses `devices[0]` and after that hijinks and hilarity ensue.

Comment: I should have said that a sound is actually produced at first. The exception is raised after 60-80 iterations of that `while (1)` loop. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Trivia note: one of the quirks of C++, `while (1) { ; }` (an infinite loop that has no possibility of a proper termination) is **undefined behavior**.  Unlikely to be a factor for the problem encountered here.

Answer (score 0):

Just the other day I encountered a similar problem when I started writing a wavetable synthesizer. In my case, the way out of this situation was to change the project configuration to x84.